# how to add a custom css class to wtform

Tags: flask-wtforms

I use wtform to create a form, and trying to add a class to the button like this

```
class CreateAddForm(FlaskForm):
     title = StringField("Movie Title", render_kw={"placeholder": "Search by movie title"},   
               validators=[DataRequired()])
     submit = SubmitField("Search", render_kw={'class': 'button'})
```

the placeholder part work, but 'class' is not working, i can't figure out why, any thoughts please?

Here is my html

```
<div class="container">

  <h1 class="heading">Search Movies</h1>
  {{ wtf.quick_form(form, novalidate=True)}}

</div>
```

I search online, can't find a solution